# Phalcon log module event errors

Tags: logging, pdo, event-handling, phalcon

I am trying to log all of the MySQL errors into a file [when a query fails]

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/db.html#profiling-sql-statements
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#logging-low-level-sql-statements

Both of these links talk about logging SQL queries with events, however I'd like to log only in the case that there's an error in the PDO.

Any ideas how to do that? :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use try catch in order to catch PDO error and log them

```
try {
    $person = Person::find(1);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // Log error here or do alternative method
}
```

Comment: i am trying to make something that will log everything automatically, without try, catch for each query..